# Widget doesn't return

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to return a ListView.builder but it doesn't seem to happen with the code below. I have just started to learn to use flutter and I am trying to implement flutter_insta before moving to the actual API. With the code below I receive the first debug message to the console but the second one never comes. Does anyone have any idea why does this happen? I don't get any error messages either.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String _username = "xxx";
  FlutterInsta flutterInsta = FlutterInsta();
  List<String> images = new List<String>();
  bool pressed = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Feed preview'),
      ),

      body: homePage(),
    );
  }

  Widget homePage(){
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Load photos"),
            onPressed: () async {
              setState(() {
                pressed = true;
                printDetails(_username);
              });//get Data
            },
          ),
        ]
      )
    );
  }

  Future printDetails(String username) async  {
      await flutterInsta.getProfileData(username);
      setState(() {
        this.images = flutterInsta.feedImagesUrl;
      });
      _buildSuggestions();
  }

  Widget _buildSuggestions() {
    print("debug");
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: /*1*/ (context, i) {
        print("debug1");
        if (i.isOdd) return Divider(); /*2*/

        final index = i ~/ 2; /*3*/
        return _buildRow(images[index]);
      });
  }

  Widget _buildRow(String url) {
    print("moi");
    return ListTile(
      trailing: Image.network(url)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add full code of your screen?

Comment: @fartem I did that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_buildSuggestions` have to be used somewhere in the widget tree.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String _username = "xxx";
  FlutterInsta flutterInsta = FlutterInsta();
  List<String> images = new List<String>();
  bool pressed = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Feed preview'),
      ),

      body: homePage(),
    );
  }

  Widget homePage(){
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(child: _buildSuggestions()),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Load photos"),
            onPressed: () async {
              setState(() {
                pressed = true;
                printDetails(_username);
              });//get Data
            },
          ),
        ]
      )
    );
  }

  Future printDetails(String username) async  {
      await flutterInsta.getProfileData(username);
      setState(() {
        this.images = flutterInsta.feedImagesUrl;
      });
  }

  Widget _buildSuggestions() {
    print("debug");
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: /*1*/ (context, i) {
        print("debug1");
        if (i.isOdd) return Divider(); /*2*/

        final index = i ~/ 2; /*3*/
        return _buildRow(images[index]);
      });
  }

  Widget _buildRow(String url) {
    print("moi");
    return ListTile(
      trailing: Image.network(url)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't add child there without an error ("The named parameter 'child' cannot be added there")

Comment: This solves the original problem but produces a new error since "images" is empty before button is pressed. However I was able to solve that by simply checking for that and returning null in case needed

Answer (score 0):

You need to render to `_buildSuggestion` in widget tree first.

You need to put `itemCount` to `ListView.Builder`

Checkout: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html

Comment: "You need to render to _buildSuggestion in widget tree first." How would you do that with my code?